# Working with custom data types

Tags: c, types

The FreeType library defines quite a few [basic data types](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html), but I'm not quite sure how to use them. I'm trying to use the [FT_Get_Glyph_Name](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Get_Glyph_Name) method, which takes this form:

```
FT_Get_Glyph_Name(FT_Face face, FT_UInt glyph_index, FT_Pointer buffer, FT_UInt buffer_max );
```

So I have this code:

```
FT_Face = face;
FT_Pointer = name;
FT_Get_Glyph_Name(face, 0, name, 45);
```

This works fine, but I'm not sure how to actually get a string representation of the name (to use with `printf` for example). How do I get from `FT_Pointer` to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation link :

> The glyph name is truncated to fit within the buffer if it is too
>   long. The returned string is always zero-terminated.

`FT_Pointer` is a typedef on void*.

A simple cast is sufficient :

```
char name[100];
FT_Get_Glyph_Name(face, 0, (FT_Pointer) name, 100);
printf("Name : '%s'\n", name);
```

You can also use FT_Pointer type variables and cast them to (char *).

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I'm not sure I fully understand the purpose of `FT_Pointer` though - it doesn't seem to actually do anything useful (I'm sure it does, I just don't see it yet)...